# How to get all the registered targets from a target group via AWS CLI command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-nlb

How to get all the registered targets from a target group via AWS CLI command?
FYI, describe health is not working.
Targets type: IP

Comment: Did you try anything to achieve that?

Comment: FYI @Marcin
Yes, I have tried the below command.
`aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn ${TG} --query 'TargetHealthDescriptions[*].Target.Id'`

But it's not giving me the desired output.(I need only targets ip addresses)

Answer (score 3):

> I need only targets ip addresses

That is exactly what your command `aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn ${TG} --query 'TargetHealthDescriptions[*].Target.Id'` is going to do for target types if IP. Since you are using "Targets type: IP" there are no problems with your command.